# does authentication_token for simple_token_authentication expires?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, api, devise, token, restful-authentication

i have an api feeding mobile apps and im using [simple_token_authentication](https://github.com/gonzalo-bulnes/simple_token_authentication) for users login and register. The thing is i want to keep the user logged in as long as he doesn't himself close the app or log out.

I guess there might be something on [devise](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise) initializer, but considering simple_token_authentication is an external gem, maybe not. Does anyone know?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There was [discussion](https://github.com/gonzalo-bulnes/simple_token_authentication/issues/34) on the simple_token_authentication gem about having sign-out functionality but the project owner decided against it. The token is valid for as long as you want it to be valid.